# Loss function exhibits strange behavior during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am building a Deep Learning model for regression:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=np.shape(X_train)[1:]),
    keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=30, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2),
    keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=20, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(30, tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(20, tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(3)
])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])

model.fit(
    X_train, 
    Y_train,
    epochs=300,
    batch_size=32,
    validation_split=0.2,
    shuffle=True,
    callbacks=[early_stopping]
)
```

During training, the loss function (and MAE) exhibit this strange behavior:

[image]

[image]

What does this trend indicate? Could it mean that the model is overfitting?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your optimiser changes (decreases) the learning rate at those sudden change curvy points.

Answer (score 0):

I think, There is an issue with your dataset. I have seen that your training and validation losses are precisely the same value, which is practically not possible.

Please check your dataset and shuffle it before splitting.